# How can I jump over values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I need to jump over values in a list (from 100 to 100) and wrote the following code:

I need to multiply the values in `I` from 100 to 100:

```
lenI = len(I)
bkgnoise=[]
i=0
while i < lenI:
    rvalue = random.random()
    bkgnoise.append(I[i]*rvalue)
    i+=100
```

But I keep getting 'exceptions.ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension'

Comment: What type is a? What type is b? Can you provide the context for this code?

Comment: Please edit to show us where and you you define a and b( are they x and y you mentionned?)

Comment: There is nothing in this code that has anything to do with `x` and `y` and dimensions.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters. Your error has nothing to do with jumping over values; it seems to be stemming from a and b having different dimensions. When you try to append one to the other, Python can't make sense of it. Is a by any chance a numpy array?

Comment: Your new post is better, but we still need to know what I looks like. Not what's in it, but what its dimensions are. Is it a list of lists? Is it a numpy ndarray? Your error seems to come from the builtin python append function. Maybe I[i] is a list of lists?

Comment: Yes, it is a numpy ndarray.

Comment: Then the problem is likely that I[i] and bkgnoise have different dimesions.

Answer (score 2):

To jump over values in a list, you might try just making a for loop that counts by 100s.

```
for i in xrange(0,20000,100):
     print i
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? Can you post the code from that?

Comment: Your problem is not jumping over values, but has to do with appending lists with different dimensions. Try to simplify your code as much as you can until you stop getting the error - narrow down the source of the problem.